# How to make a div take the remaining height of its parent that has height fit-content and a max-height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div take all the remaining height of its parent when the parent doesn't have a fixed height.

Here is an example illustrating the problem:

```css
.Container
{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    max-height: 50px;
}
.ActionBar
{
    background-color: #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
}
.TableContainer
{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
.TableWrapper
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.TableMenu
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="Container">
        <div class="ActionBar">
            Action
        </div>
        <div class="TableContainer">
            <div class="TableMenu">
                Menu
            </div>
            <div class="TableWrapper">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                        <td>cell</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example, i'm trying to make "TableContainer" take all the remaining height of "Container", but the height attribute does nothing.
"TableContainer" does what i want when setting the height of "Container" to a fixed value, but not when it is set to fit-content or any relative value.

Comment: Your container has a max-height of 50px, what remaining height is there?

Comment: The container has a max-height of 50px but has 2 elements inside it, it has the ActionBar and the TableContainer, what i ment by remaining height is: (Container height - ActionBar height)

Comment: That means the "remaining height" is likely to be c. 30px... that's not very much for an entire table.

Comment: The snippet i provided was just an example illustrating the problem, these are not the real heights I'm using.

Comment: Then demonstrate the *actual* issue without the unrealistic max-height.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To make your `TableWrapper` automatically take up the remaining height, you need to use a `grid` in your container. Then, specifying this value:

```
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; /* add this line */
```

allows you to tell your table to set the first row to `auto`, taking up the height of the content, and `1fr` means that the second row will take up the rest. The `grid-auto-flow: row` property specifies that the grid items should be placed in rows.

And then, you define for each cell, the number of columns and rows it will take. In your case, you have 2 rows and 4 columns (1 menu and 3 cells). So you can define for each cell:

- ActionBar: `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 4;` it starts in row 1 and ends in row 1, it starts in column 1 and ends in column 4.
- TableContainer: `grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 4;` it starts in row 2 and ends in row 2, it starts in column 4 and ends in column 4.

You need to know the number of columns/rows in the table in advance. If you need to generate columns or rows dynamically in your table (other than in the `TableWrapper`), you will probably have to use javascript to generate the css accordingly or modify the code a bit.

If needed, you can play around with an interactive css grid here: https://grid.layoutit.com/

But here's the code for your case:

```css
.Container
{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; /* auto is for first line, 1fr is for the second line in grid */
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}
.ActionBar
{
    background-color: #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 200; /* on scroll, keep your action bar first */
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4;
}
.TableContainer
{
    display: flex;
    max-height: inherit; /* Take max-height of parent */
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 4 / 4;
}
.TableWrapper
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
.TableMenu
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="Container">
        <div class="ActionBar">
            Action
        </div>
        <div class="TableContainer">
            <div class="TableMenu">
                Menu
            </div>
            <div class="TableWrapper">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell 1</td>
                        <td>cell 1</td>
                        <td>cell 1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell 2</td>
                        <td>cell 2</td>
                        <td>cell 2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell 3</td>
                        <td>cell 3</td>
                        <td>cell 3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell 4</td>
                        <td>cell 4</td>
                        <td>cell 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell 5</td>
                        <td>cell 5</td>
                        <td>cell 5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your solution you are removing 18px for the ActionBar manually, im looking for a solution that does that automatically.

Comment: Please include an explanation, not just code